# Adding more than one instance of ArrayModelField item with Djongo

Tags: django, mongodb, dynamic-forms, djongo

I am using `djongo` to add `mongodb` to my application. I have a model, say `ModelA`, that takes in an `ArrayModelField` of another model `ModelB`, which is an abstract model. I get a `ModelForm` for ModelA, but it shows fields for entry of only one ModelB. How can I get a functionality like an Add button, so that more ModelB fields can be added?

I searched a lot for it and found this: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/210
but I am still unable to get it to work. I have read about formsets and dynamic formsets and believe that djongo has added the jquery dynamic formset in its own code. So while creating a class like:

```
class B(models.Model):
    # fields
    source = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container = A1,
    )
    destination = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container = A2,
    )
```

I am not able to decide how to do this. I can do this for a self-maintained template, but I don't want to change the default admin, or customize it.